# Libgdx Creating On Screen Controls

Tags: libgdx

I am working on libgdx.I am using this example https://github.com/oakes/libgdx-examples/tree/master/SuperKoalio/core/src/net/sekao/superkoalio to create a game.

I want to add controls on the screen, so that user can move left,right,up using the buttons.I used this "Controller" class https://github.com/BrentAureli/ControllerDemo/tree/master/core/src/com/brentaureli/overlaydemo

But I am not able to see any controls on the screen.Can any one please provide me solution to fix this.

Comment: Are you sure you have implemented the controller class exactly as shown in the overlay demo?

Comment: Ya.I followed this tutorial.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z4Vqkp_ve3I I don't know where I am missing.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't create your own buttons for this? This is very simple in LibGDX using Scene2d.